# How to get the values from the Model and into Views Javascript (Visual Studio 2015 mvc)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Models code:

```
public class graph_user
{
    public  List<int> year { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Views code side:

```
@model  IEnumerable testing.Models.graph_user

function generateChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    for (i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
        data.addColumn('string',);
        data.addRow();
    }
}
```

Basically I want to obtains the values from list year from within the Models to the javascript which is seen declared in my views.

Comment: Is you model `graph_user` or `IEnumerable<graph_user>`?

Comment: Oops You're right, it's suppose to me @model graph_user thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your model is actually `@model graph_user` and not `@model  IEnumerable<graph_user>` (your current definition would not compile)

You can assign you models collection to a javascript variable using

```
var yearList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.year))
```

Then iterate over it using

```
$.each(yearList, function(index, item) {
  var year = item;
  // do something with it
});
```

Side note: Recommend you follow normal naming conventions and name your property `Years` - plural - (not `year`) and your class `GraphUser`

Comment: Why do you recommend to represent object as string and than parse it instead of directly representing object in JavaScript?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Not sure what you mean. What would you suggest?

Comment: `var yearList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.year));`

Comment: I'm guessing I could also use var yearList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.year)) and then to display i do yearlist[1] ??

Comment: @JohnLington, You can use either the `for (i = 0; i < yearList.length; i++) {` or the `$.each()` loop - both will work.

Comment: Okay i'll do    for (i = 0; i < year.length; i++) 
{ something to display yearlist[1]}  thank you so much for help!!!